# Static images loads really slow

Tags: image, performance

So, my **assets folder** in Angular app has a **size of about 1GB** where **images** are close to **134MB** and a video of 738 MB. A component which displays ***these images take about 3-4 seconds to render in local***, and it takes ***more than a minute*** on a application which is deployed to ***PCF(even after using AOT).***

> Strange thing is that the components renders just in fraction of
>   seconds if we revisit it.
>
> I have tried using lazy loading for images by using deferload. But,
>   still the problem not resolved.

Could someone share their thoughts on this.

[image: Network statistics attached]

Comment: please provide the output of chrome developer tools/network tab.  for sure its the time to download the images from whatever source you get them.  any reason why the asset size is soo big?  are it many images with normal size and/or a few huge ones.  Pls provide code.  In general, you could optimize your images to make them much smaller, use thumbnails as a start (and full size on click),  use paging type of techniques not to load them all at once (only what you need), use a CDN, etc etc

Comment: Hi, updated the question with network stats.

Comment: first you need to determine which image size and quality you really need.  As from the info above I 'guestimate' that your image size is like min. 2500x2000 pixels in full quality.   So in my oppinion this is of no use. size it down to whatever size you need and optimize online to get a reference size. (site like : http://www.imageoptimizer.net/ and others).  I think you should be able to fit your image in the 1-2MB range or even less

Comment: In addition,  you load a video of 700+ MB on page load / to fill you component?  you should use a thumbnail and then based on click download the real file.

Comment: Thanks @jcuypers, I agree with you. Currently I am trying to figure out how do I go about streaming the video.

Answer (score 0):

Mostlikely fetching such big images causes the app to load slow.
It is probably unnecessary to have such big image size. You could try to resize the images with something like lambda resize image.

Also if you revisit the site all the data is already cached in the browser. You could try to disable cache in the network tab and it should be slow on every visit of the site

Answer (score -1):

You can use npm install package **`ng-lazyload-image`**

Fine the url for description and usage docs

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-lazyload-image

Comment: lazyload will not solve the problem.  having suck big image sizes is just senseless.  in general the question was about rendering time in different scenarios